# How to create a breadcrumb for pages?

Tags: breadcrumb

I would like to display the 'file path' in the conventional position on a page on my WordPress site. Something like this:

[image: example]

Does anybody know if this is possible without manually typing it onto each page (not really feasible)?

Comment: They're called Breadcrumbs. Search for that and you'll find a bunch of plugins.

Comment: This path is home > [category] > [post-title]

you can add links and give whatever text you want. you can design the template accordingly, if you don't want to use plugin.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of plugins that offer a breadcrumb, but you can also create your own.

To create a simple breadcrumb, you'll need 2 functions. One to create a chain of categories, and one to generate the breadcrumb itself.

### Create a Chain of Categories

This function will generate a list of clickable categories, for when you are on a single post, page or category. We will use this in the breadcrumb later.

```
function wpse_get_category_parents( $id, $link = false, $separator = '/', $nicename = false, $visited = array(), $iscrumb=false ) {
    $chain = '';
    $parent = get_term( $id, 'category' );
    if ( is_wp_error( $parent ) ) {
        return $parent;
    }
    if ( $nicename ) {
        $name = $parent->slug;
    } else {
        $name = $parent->name;
    }
    if ( $parent->parent && ( $parent->parent != $parent->term_id ) && !in_array( $parent->parent, $visited ) ) {
        $visited[] = $parent->parent;
        $chain .= wpse_get_category_parents( $parent->parent, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited , $iscrumb);
    }
    if (is_rtl()){
        $sep_direction ='\\';
    } else {
        $sep_direction ='/';
    }
    if ($iscrumb){
        $chain .= '<li><span class="sep">'.$sep_direction.'</span><a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $parent->term_id ) ) . '"><span>'.$name.'</span></a></li>' . $separator ;
    } elseif ( $link && !$iscrumb) {
        $chain .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $parent->term_id ) ) . '">'.$name.'</a>' . $separator ;
    } else {
        $chain .= $name.$separator;
    }
    return $chain;
}
```

### Generate a Breadcrumb

We'll write a function and use conditionals to generate different outputs based on different locations. We will use the above function here.

```
function wpse_get_breadcrumbs() {
    global $wp_query;
        if (is_rtl()){
            $sep_direction ='\\';
        } else {
            $sep_direction ='/';
        }?>
    <ul><?php
        // Adding the Home Page  ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>"><span> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></span></a></li><?php
        if ( ! is_front_page() ) {
            // Check for categories, archives, search page, single posts, pages, the 404 page, and attachments
            if ( is_category() ) {
                $cat_obj     = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
                $thisCat     = get_category( $cat_obj->term_id );
                $parentCat   = get_category( $thisCat->parent );
                if($thisCat->parent != 0) {
                    $cat_parents = wpse_get_category_parents( $parentCat, true, '', false, array(), true );
                }
                if ( $thisCat->parent != 0 && ! is_wp_error( $cat_parents ) ) {
                    echo $cat_parents;
                }
                echo '<li><span class="sep">'.$sep_direction.'</span><a href="'.get_category_link($thisCat).'"><span>'.single_cat_title( '', false ).'</span></a></li>';
            } elseif ( is_archive() && ! is_category() ) { ?>
                <li><span class="sep"><?php echo $sep_direction;?></span> <?php _e( 'Archives' ); ?></li><?php
            } elseif ( is_search() ) { ?>
                <li><span class="sep"><?php echo $sep_direction;?></span> <?php _e( 'Search Results' ); ?></li><?php
            } elseif ( is_404() ) { ?>
                <li><span class="sep"><?php echo $sep_direction;?></span> <?php _e( '404 Not Found' ); ?></li><?php
            } elseif ( is_singular() ) {
                $category    = get_the_category();
                $category_id = get_cat_ID( $category[0]->cat_name );
                $cat_parents = wpse_get_category_parents( $category_id, true, '',false, array(), true );
                if ( ! is_wp_error( $cat_parents ) ) {
                    echo $cat_parents;
                }?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><span class="sep"><?php echo $sep_direction;?></span><?php the_title();?></a>
                </li><?php
            } elseif ( is_singular( 'attachment' ) ) { ?>
                <li>
                    <span class="sep"><?php echo $sep_direction;?></span> <?php the_title(); ?>
                </li><?php
            } elseif ( is_page() ) {
                $post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
                if ( $post->post_parent == 0 ) { ?>
                    <li><?php _e( '<span class="sep">/</span>' ); the_title(); ?></li><?php
                } else {
                    $title = the_title( '','', false );
                    $ancestors = array_reverse( get_post_ancestors( $post->ID ) );
                    array_push( $ancestors, $post->ID );
                    foreach ( $ancestors as $ancestor ) {
                        if ( $ancestor != end( $ancestors ) ) { ?>
                            <li>
                                <span class="sep"><?php echo $sep_direction;?></span><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $ancestor ) ); ?>"> <span><?php echo strip_tags( apply_filters( 'single_post_title', get_the_title( $ancestor ) ) ); ?></span></a>
                            </li><?php
                        } else { ?>
                            <li>
                                <span class="sep"><?php echo $sep_direction;?></span><?php echo strip_tags( apply_filters( 'single_post_title', get_the_title( $ancestor ) ) ); ?>
                            </li><?php
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } ?>
    </ul><?php
}
```

### Output the Breadcrumb

After including both of above functions in your theme's `functions.php` file, you should use the below code in your theme's header to output the breadcrumb:

```
if( ! is_home() ) {
    wpse_get_breadcrumbs();
}
```

This will hide the breadcrumb on homepage, since it's not really required.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any plugin you can add custom breadcrumbs to your website. Please try the sample code for simple breadcrumb( in functions.php)

```
function the_breadcrumb() {
    echo '<ul id="crumbs">';
if (!is_home()) {
    echo '<li><a href="';
    echo get_option('home');
    echo '">';
    echo 'Home';
    echo "</a></li>";
    if (is_category() || is_single()) {
        echo '<li>';
        the_category(' </li><li> ');
        if (is_single()) {
            echo "</li><li>";
            the_title();
            echo '</li>';
        }
    } elseif (is_page()) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo the_title();
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
elseif (is_tag()) {single_tag_title();}
elseif (is_day()) {echo"<li>Archive for "; the_time('F jS, Y'); echo'</li>';}
elseif (is_month()) {echo"<li>Archive for "; the_time('F, Y'); echo'</li>';}
elseif (is_year()) {echo"<li>Archive for "; the_time('Y'); echo'</li>';}
elseif (is_author()) {echo"<li>Author Archive"; echo'</li>';}
elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) {echo "<li>Blog Archives"; echo'</li>';}
elseif (is_search()) {echo"<li>Search Results"; echo'</li>';}
echo '</ul>';
```

}

Add the following short code in pages you want to show the breadcrumb

```
<?php the_breadcrumb(); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Breadcrumbs are an important part of almost every good website. These little navigational aids don’t just tell people where they are on your site, but they also help Google work out how your site is structured. That’s why it makes a lot of sense to add these helpful little pointers. Let’s take a look at how breadcrumbs work.

you can Install https://yoast.com/ free plugin.